# Skip a same combination in Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a List filteredList where and I am streaming over each element and using for each to set some items

```
filteredList.parallelStream().forEach(s->{

            ARChaic option=new ARChaic();
            option.setCpu(s.getNoOfCPU());
            option.setMem(s.getMemory());
            option.setStorage(s.getStorage());
            option.setOperatingSystem(s.getOperationSystem());


           ARChaic newOption= providerDes.getLatest(option); //this is a external service
        s.setCloudMemory(newOption.getMem());
        s.setCloudCPU(newOption.getCpu());
        s.setCloudStorage(newOption.getStorage());
        s.setCloudOS(newOption.getOperatingSystem());

});
```

The goal is to call this service but if the above option is same then take the old one to call.

For Example- if two server have same memory,cpu,os and storage then it will call **getLatest** only once.

Suppose at position 1 and 7 in filteredList I have same config then I shouldn't be calling getLatest again at 7 since I already have previous option value which I will set it 7(Working done after service call)

Comment: Can you convert `filteredList` to a set so that you won't have any duplicates to begin with? do you need all server objects in `filteredList` at the end?

Comment: filteredList is a List<Server> server has attributes(cpu,memory,storage,os name) in its POJO  which might be same

Comment: @user7 Yes I need to save all servers at the end also I cannot skip server completely because I just want to skip one service but still I want to store values of that skipped server for the specification which is same as this server.

The whole logic is that I don't want to call this service again again for the same option value. I hope this sums it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `equals` and `hashcode` to your `Server` class to denote when two Server instances are equal. From your description, you will have to take into account and compare the memory, cpu, os, and storage.

After this, you can map the `filteredList` as a `Map<Server, List<Server>>` to get unique servers as the key and the value will have all the repeated server instances. You will call the service once for each key in the map, but after you get the result, you can update all the server instances that are the value of the map with the result.

```
Map<Server, List<Server>> uniqueServers = filteredList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.mapping(Function.identity(),
                    Collectors.toList())));

uniqueServers.entrySet().parallelStream().forEach(entry -> {
        Server currentServer = entry.getKey(); //Current server
        ARChaic option=new ARChaic();
        option.setCpu(currentServer.getNoOfCPU());
        option.setMem(currentServer.getMemory());
        option.setStorage(currentServer.getStorage());
        option.setOperatingSystem(currentServer.getOperationSystem());

        ARChaic newOption= providerDes.getLatest(option); //this is a external service
        //update all servers with the result.
        entry.getValue().forEach(server -> {
            server.setCloudMemory(newOption.getMem());
            server.setCloudCPU(newOption.getCpu());
            server.setCloudStorage(newOption.getStorage());
            server.setCloudOS(newOption.getOperatingSystem());
        });
    });
```

Comment: you missed some key points my whole idea is to skip the getLatest call when options are same and question arises if we skip that line then what do we set after the service since service is returning itself ARChaic newOption but this is also need to be figured out.

Comment: In short line if you see my code properly I don't want to call getLatest everytime even if ARChaic 'option' is same instead set the newOption value previously got for this option(which is same as other option/s)

Comment: @Plootus Wouldn't the `ARChaic` returned by the service the same for two service objects with same cpu,memory,storage,os? Here, I populate the `setCloud*` for *all* the server objects with the same configuration (since we have already grouped in the map). I don't quite understand your point. Please elaborate/clarify

Comment: Going by your point, if you two objects at index 1 and 7 that have same config, we will have one map entry (and hence call service once) and after the service returns ArChaic object we populate the `setCloud*` fields of both the objects

Comment: ok so do I need to add hashcode and equals for cpu, memory, storage and os to check the instances also plus your above code? Also I will check in this code test it then respond as correct answer or else I post other queries. Please respond

Comment: and also I need to put hashcode and equals in ARChaic or Server POJO?

Comment: Yes. You need to add it to Server POJO. If you can show the server POJO, I can update the answer showing you how to implement equals and hashcode if you are not sure

Comment: No I actually autogenerated it with fields only of cpu,memory,storage and os name...I will check it's complete working for all Cases then respond.